# Can't call Openweather map API

Tags: java, android, weather

I'm currently learning how to create Android app by following Udacity's Android course on building a weather app. One requirement is to call openweathermap API using `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?id=7839805&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&appid=[my api key]`.

However, I always end up with

```
{"cod":401, "message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."}
```

How to get the correct API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an account on openweathermap. You will get your API key. Replace it in the URL :

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?id=7839805&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&appid=[my api key]
```

and you will be able to get the correct JSON response.

Comment: that's what I did, i copied and pasted my API key into appid=[this is where i pasted the api key], but still end up with the same result :(

Comment: remove [] and place your key directly

Comment: omg, something so simple took me forever... thank you so so much!

Comment: @TonyStark Do as Mehta told you. Remove the square brackets.

Comment: Thank you both for helping out!! really appreciate it!!